# Работа с циклом For

Tags: php

```
<?For ($i=1; $i<5; $i++){?>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name="[$i][code]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="[$i?][name]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="[$i?][groups]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Группа товара"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="[$i?][unit]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th>
  </tr>
  </div>
<? }?>
```

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы в `name` вставлялось значение `$i`. Т.е. чтобы получилось 4 блока input, в каждом блоке чтобы `name` был `[1][code]`;...;`[1][unit]`, а в следующем `[2][code]`;...;`[2].[unit]`. Или у меня верно все?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить разметку, `<?php echo i; ?>`

Comment: Я блин был уверен, что если так сделать, то просто тупо распечатается 1,2,3,4 и все.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?for($i=1; $i<5; $i++){?>
  <tr>
    <th><input type="text" name="<?=[$i][code]?>" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="<?=[$i][name]?>" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="<?=[$i][groups]?>" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Группа товара"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="<?=[$i][unit]?>" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th>
  </tr>
  </div> <!-- Это точно должно тут быть? -->
<? }?>
```